# footer div background color not displaying in browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background

Even through the browser shows the css style in the sources, the background color is not displaying. Any thoughts?

```css
.footer {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #009DDC;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <li>&copy; Cedar Flute, 2022.</li>
  <li style="float:right">Web Design: Leagh Branner.</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid. List items must be children of a list.

Comment: I see background color in the demo above. Please revise to explain the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might be closer to what you are looking for...

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #009DDC;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <ul>
    <li>&copy; Cedar Flute, 2022.</li>
    <li>Web Design: Leagh Branner.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your color still doesnt want to show you could use

`background-color:blue !important;`

Using "!important" basically forces the CSS style

Answer (score -1):

It worked fine for me. Are you sure you're CSS file is linked correctly? My file was in a CSS folder and I have this in the HTML head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
```

Comment: It was stated that the styles appear in the browser.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to use flexbox.

```
<ul class="footer">
    <li>&copy; Cedar Flute, 2022.</li>
    <li>Web Design: Leagh Branner.</li>
</ul>
```

```
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #009ddc;
}
```

If you still wanted to use float ( would recommend to switch to flexbox) -

```
<ul class="footer">
  <li style="float:right">Web Design: Leagh Branner.</li>
  <li>&copy; Cedar Flute, 2022.</li>
</ul>
```

```
.footer {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #009ddc;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

or

```
<ul class="footer">
    <li style="display:inline">&copy; Cedar Flute, 2022.</li>
    <li style="float:right;">Web Design: Leagh Branner.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The first option you shared worked! Do you know why my attempt failed?

Comment: `li` is a block level element. When an element is floated, it is taken out of the normal flow of the document (though still remaining part of it). When the 2nd `li` is set to float , since the 1st `li` is already occupying the space , it goes to the next line but still floats to the right

Comment: `<li style="background:blue;display:inline">&copy; Cedar Flute, 2022.</li><li style="float:right;background:yellow">Web Design: Leagh Branner.</li>`
Here using background colors it can be clearly seen how the document flow is.

Comment: How does this answer a question about background color? Also, any solution should show valid HTML. List items cannot be children of a div.